# Comparing hash results always returns false even if they're exactly the same

Tags: java, mysql, hash, cryptography

So I'm writing a java program that takes a username and password from the user, retrieve the hashed password from a database (mysql), and authenticate the user. The hashed password and salt are saved as TEXT datatype in my database. My problem is that when I compare the stored password and the one that the user entered (after running the hashing algorithm on it of course), the result is always false. I copied the 2 hashes and compared them in another program they turned out to be equal. Here's my code (please ignore the fact that my code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks I'm planning on fixing that later:

```
public class Security {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UserNotExistingException {
    Security s=new Security();
    s.signUp("John.Smith", "John Smith", "text@lau.edu", "test");
    System.out.println(s.Authenticate("John.Smith" , "test"));
}

public boolean Authenticate(String username, String password) throws UserNotExistingException {
    String dbpass = null;
    byte[] salt = null;
    try {
        // Load driver for connecting to db
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Establishing connection to db
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vote sys", "root", "");
        // Creating statement object to be executed on dbms
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select  pass, salt from user_acc where username = '" + username + "';");

        if (rs.next()) {
            dbpass = rs.getString(2);
            String temp = rs.getString(2);
            System.out.println(temp);
            salt = temp.getBytes();
        }
        for (byte i : salt)
            System.out.print(i);
        System.out.println();
        // Terminating connection to db
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    if (dbpass == null || salt == null)
        throw new UserNotExistingException("User " + username + " doesn't exist");

    try { //this is where im facing the problem, the condition is always returning true when its not
        String hashed=generateHash(password, salt);
        System.out.println(hashed);
        if (hashed.compareTo(dbpass)!=0)
            return false;


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}

private static String generateHash(String password, byte[] salt)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    int iterations = 1000;
    char[] chars = password.toCharArray();

    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(chars, salt, iterations, 64 * 8);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte[] hash = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    return iterations + ":" + toHex(salt) + ":" + toHex(hash);
}

private static byte[] getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    sr.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}

private static String toHex(byte[] array) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
    String hex = bi.toString(16);
    int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
    if (paddingLength > 0) {
        return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
    } else {
        return hex;
    }
}

public void signUp(String username, String name, String email,  String password) {
    String dbuser = "", dbemail = "";
    try {
        // Load driver for connecting to db
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        // Establishing connection to db
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vote sys", "root", "");
        // Creating statement object to be executed on dbms
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select  username, email from user_acc where username = '" + username
                + "' or email = '" + email + "';");

        if (rs.next()) {
            dbuser = rs.getString(2);
            dbemail = rs.getString(2);
        }
        if (!dbuser.equals("") || !dbemail.equals(""))
            throw new UserNotExistingException("Username or email already exists");

        byte[] salt = getSalt();
        for (int i = 0; i < salt.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(salt[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        String temp= new String(salt);
        System.out.println(temp);
        String hashedPass = generateHash(password, salt);
        System.out.println(hashedPass);
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `user_acc`(`username`, `name`, `email`, `pass`, `salt`) VALUES ('"
                + username + "','" + name + "','" + email + "','" + hashedPass + "','" + temp + "');");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to store the salt as a string with (where `salt` is a `byte[]`):

```
String temp= new String(salt);
```

and later to extract it:

```
salt = temp.getBytes();
```

You can’t convert a byte array into a string and back like this and expect to retrieve the same bytes. The [docs for (`String(byte[])`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-) say:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified.

Since your password format already includes the salt as a hex string, you don’t need to store the salt separately anyway. Instead, extract the hex strings of the salt and password hash from this string, convert them to `byte[]`, and use them in the comparison.